# Один домен для веб-сайта и игрового сервера

Tags: ip, dns, site, gameserver

Замечал на некоторых игровых проектов что вместо стандартного ip адреса игрового сервера используют домен, а домен в свою очередь через браузер заходит на сайт.
Суть вопроса, возможен ли так, что с одного домена одного уровня заходить через браузер на сайт, а через игру на сервер? И как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Сервер игры поставить на серв с сайтом.
Сайт на 80 (433) порту, а игра на другом - поэтому это возможно

Comment: А возможно такое сделать, если они находятся на разных серверах?

Comment: без использования поддоменов наврятли